# Replace Java static method call by REST

Tags: java, rest, static

Assume I have a jar that calls a static method from another jar. This method only reads data and does not change any state.

I want to replace this static method call by a REST call. This means that I have to serialize the method arguments in some way and deserialize the method result.

What would be a standard way to do this?

Comment: Maybe google for "Java REST tutorial" and work through one? What would be your benefit of using a restful architecture?

Comment: I know how to write a REST service with jersey, but I don't know how to handle serialization and deserialization in this context. The reason for extracting the REST service is that the operation takes a huge amount of memory and want to run it on a server. The original operation runs on desktop pcs in our company.